# Python class structuring, getting and setting properties and inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, properties, attributes, structure

This is a problem I come across quite frequently, and I finally want to find out the most Pythonic solution for it. At its core, the situation can be described as follows:

1. A class contains some attributes that must be calculated or tested based on `__init__()` parameters.
2. Attributes may or may not allow alteration after class instantiating.
3. Attributes that are allowed to be altered must be recalculated/tested each time after doing so.
4. The class should be "inheritance friendly."

---

**Goal in example project**: A geometry module that helps with 2d shape calculations (such as the minimum distance between polygons or intersection points between lines). Lines and Polygons have quite some attributes in common, so create a `BaseGeometry` class from which the `Line` and `Polygon` classes inherit. The `BaseGeometry` attributes:

- `points` a (n,x,y) list of points that are set on instantiation and can be mutated. Each time it is set, it must be asserted to be a numpy array.
- `domain`: tuple of (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax) that describes the shape's bounds. Must be recalculated each time `points` is set, but may not be externally altered.

Below, I have written up three (simplified) solutions for approaching this problem, all with their pros and cons.

**METHOD 1**: Wrongly allows alteration of `domain` and unclear on which class attributes exist.

```
class BaseGeometry1:
    
    def __init__(self, points):
        self.set_points(points)

    def set_points(self, points):
        assert type(points) is np.ndarray
        self.points = points
        x, y = points.T
        self.domain = ((min(x), max(x), min(y), max(y)))
```

**METHOD 2**: Still allows `domain` to be altered. Clear on which attributes exist, but feels clunky/illogical. Arbitrary whether `calculate_domain()` has `points` as a parameter or just use `self.points`. `calculate_domain()` Would have to be called each time `points` is updated.

```
class BaseGeometry2:
    
    def __init__(self, points):
        self.points = self.set_points(points)
        self.domain = self.calculate_domain()

    def set_points(self, points):
        assert type(points) is np.ndarray
        return points

    def calculate_domain(self):
        x, y = self.points.T
        return (min(x), max(x), min(y), max(y))
```

**METHOD 3**: I feel like this is on the right track, but I'm still unsure about the structuring. It feels weird that `points.setter` also sets `_domain`. Also, is it bad practice to just use the @property decorators for all class attributes?

```
class BaseGeometry3:

    def __init__(self, points):
        self.points = points

    @property
    def points(self):
        return self._points

    @points.setter
    def points(self, points):
        assert type(points) is np.ndarray
        self._points = points
        x, y = points.T
        self._domain = ((min(x), max(x), min(y), max(y)))
      
    @property
    def domain(self):
        return  self._domain
```

---

My questions are as follows:

1. Is one of these methods considered conventional? Why/why not?
2. What are some additional conventions to keep in mind while approaching this problem?
3. What are some other tips or sources that can help me to improve my class structuring?
4. Would a class inheriting from GeometryBase3 have to completely redefine the `points.setter` method in order to introduce some new attributes that are calculated from `points`?

Also, I'm new to asking questions here, so any feedback on the post is welcome as well. Thanks in advance for your time and any answers!

Kind regards,

Joost

Comment: I would go for the third method. If calculating the `domain` was expensive and `points` would be set much more often then it was asked for the `domain`, you could set `_domain` to `None` in the setter of `points`, and calculate and assign it only when requested by the getter of `domain`. You don't need to redefine the setter for `points` for any on-top functionality.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please check the [tour] page for information on asking. Specifically, questions should focus on *one* thing, otherwise you could get several different answers that all equally address only part of your question. Likewise, Stack Overflow is not a good fit for opinion-based/subjective questions, which includes things like best practices recommendations, *conventions*, request for tips, etc.

Comment: Finally, meta commentary like "thanks in advance" or signatures are unnecessary; you thank people here by upvoting useful answers/comments, and accepting the answer that best solves your problem/answers your question. Likewise, every question is signed with the user card at the bottom right of the post, which includes the author's name, rep, timestamp, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the tips and explanation! On the opinion/convention rule: I completely understand that opinion-based questions are to be avoided here. However, I feel like code structuring and style is a major part of "good" programming which (for me at least) is responsible for a large portion of the time I spent thinking about my code. I aspire to become better at it, but the fact that there are many valid approaches is precisely why this feels so difficult. Is stack overflow simply not the best place for an open discussion on this topic or should I have worded my question differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no one right answer here, but I like parts of Method 2 and Method 3.

How about something like this? This uses the `descriptor` protocol, of which a `property` class is just a specific form. It adheres more to the DRY ("don't repeat yourself") principle than using a `@property` decorator for each attribute in your class.

```
class UnsettableGeometricDescriptor:
    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.name = name
        self.lookup_name = f'_{name}'

    def __get__(self, obj, type=None):
        return getattr(obj, self.lookup_name)

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        raise AttributeError(f'Attribute {self.name} cannot be set directly, use method "update_shape" instead')


class BaseGeometry4:
    def __init__(self, points):
        self.update_shape(points)

    points = UnsettableGeometricDescriptor()
    domain = UnsettableGeometricDescriptor()

    def update_shape(self, points):
        assert isinstance(points, np.ndarray), "points parameter has to be a numpy array!!!"
        self._points = points 
        x, y = points.T
        self._domain = ((min(x), max(x), min(y), max(y)))
```

The nice thing about this method is its extensibility -- if you need to add more unsettable attributes to a subclass, it's easy to do so, and you can extend update_shape() by calling super() on it in a subclass.

**What's going on here?**

If you instantiate an instance of `BaseGeometry4`, you'll find that it has a `points` attribute and a `domain` attribute, but neither can be set directly.

What's going on here, is when you "access" the `points` attribute, this invokes the `__get__` method in the `UnsettableGeometricDescriptor` class. This `__get__` method effectively just redirects you to the `_points` attribute of the `BaseGeometry4` instance in the case of the `points` attribute, and `_domain` in the case of the `domain` attribute. The `__set__` method of the descriptor just throws an exception, since you never want a user to be able to update those attributes directly. The values that these descriptor-classes defer to (`_points` and `_domain`) are set within the `update_shape()` method of `BaseGeometry4`

There's a great RealPython tutorial on the descriptor protocol [here](https://realpython.com/python-descriptors/), and the official python docs on descriptors can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html).